# Carrierwave , 2 folders in my cache folders and my files stay in my cache folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

I use carrierwave for upload sound in my app.

I use large file so  I configure my carrierwave for use move_to_cache and move_to_store but the problem is when I upload file now , in my cache folder carrierwave create 2 folder with two cache.id and 1 folder in my store.

I need when I upload file , just have 1 folder in the cache folder and 1 folder in my store folder. And In my cache folder I want my file was delete , but actually my file stay in my cache folder.

I hope i was clear.

I give you my sound_uploader.rb

```
class SoundUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
before :store , :print

def print(new_file)
  puts ("PRINT CAAAAACHE")
  puts (cache_id)
end

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

   def store_dir
  "tmp/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/store/#{model.id}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "tmp/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/cache/#{model.id}"
  end
  def move_to_cache
    puts("MOVE TO CACHE ")
    false
  end

  def move_to_store
    puts("MOVE TO STORE ")
    true
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(3ga 3gp 3g2 3gpp 3gp2 m4a m4b m4p m4v m4r mp4 aac flac flv avi asf wma wmv dpx mkv mka mks bwf mpg mpeg mp1 mp2 mp3
      m1v m1a m2a mpa mpv rm mov ogm ogg ogv oga ogx nut riff webm weba wav mxf asx ts aiff aif aifc au snd caf)
  end


  def filename
    model.title = original_filename if model.title.to_s ==  ''
    "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  protected
  def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
  end
end
```

thank's for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The likely reason for this is that you're using cancan's `load_and_authorize_resource` or load_resource, and you forgot creating the model object in the controller action `(@song = Song.new(params[:song])`, so the resource is being created twice, which causes carrierwave to move the file to cache twice.